# How to add lazy loading manually with a3 lazy load plugin in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, lazy-loading

I’d like to know how can I add the lazy loading functionality of the [a3 lazy load Wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/a3-lazy-load/) manually to certain images. For example how would I add it to this code which is integrated into a page template on my site:

```
<img class="some-class" src="source-of-my-image.png" />
```

Thanks so much in advance for a reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `src` attribute with `data-src`.

i.e.: Change `<img src="my-image.png">` to `<img data-src="my-image.png">`.

For more info go to: https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt#usage

Answer (score 0):

It is implemented in the following way:

```
 img src="https://test.com/wp-content/speed.svg" loading="lazy" data-src="https://test.com/wp-content/speed.svg"
```

Read more: https://www.plerdy.com/blog/lazy-loading-setup-wordpress/